# I cannot seem to get my regular expressions in Perl to recognize underscore (_) characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a series of regular expressions in Perl to extract certain types of data from a file. For some reason, I cannot seem to get Perl to match anything lines of data that have an underscore (`_`) in them.

If I want to get lines that start with

```
"Ch2    Flybase exon    "
```

Or

```
"Ch3    Flybase exon    "
```

(The white spaces are tab characters), the following code works well:

```
if ($_ =~ m/^Ch[ 2-3]   Flybase exon    /) {print outputFile;}
```

However, if I want to match the lines with more complex chromosome names (i.e. more than just the letters 'Ch' followed by a number), such as:

```
Ch4_group1
Ch4_group2
Ch4_group3
Ch4_group4
Ch4_group5
ChXL_group1a
ChXL_group1e
ChXL_group3a
ChXL_group3b
ChXR_group3a
ChXR_group5
ChXR_group6
ChXR_group8
Unknown_group_1
Unknown_group_10
Unknown_group_100
Unknown_group_101
```

I have tried the following codes without success:

```
if ($_ =~ m/^Ch4_group[1-5] Flybase exon    /) {print outputFile;}
if ($_ =~ m/^ChX._group[0-9]+[a-z]* Flybase exon    /) {print outputFile;}
if ($_ =~ m/^Unknown_group_[0-9]+   Flybase exon    /) {print outputFile;}
if ($_ =~ m/^Unknown_singleton_[0-9]+   Flybase exon    /) {print outputFile;}
```

I have also tried including a `\` in front of the `_`, but this did not help.

Comment: Have you tried using `\t` in your regex?

Comment: I gave it a try but it did not change anything. The expressions with underscores are not being matched for some reason

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, all the lines match using your regexes. I seriously doubt that underscore is your problem. More likely, you have some whitespace that is not what you think it is. Use `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $_;`  to see what kind of whitespace you have in your strings. Also, unless you need stricter matching, you do not need to match trailing whitespace, and the whitespace in the middle can simply be matched by `\s+`.

Comment: You might also check and make sure that the `ord()` number of underscore is 95, and not some odd version of it. I.e. `print ord for split //`

Comment: The ord is 95 and the whitespace characters in the file are just tab characters. I did a simple control+F search on the target file (open in Notepad++) for the expression "Ch4_group[1-5]\s+Flybase\s+exon\s" and had no trouble finding matches. I really cannot work out why Perl will not recognize these lines when there seems to be  perfect match.

Comment: The following line, for example, should be detected:
Ch4_group1 FlyBase exon 127 138 . - . ID=dpse_GLEANR_16817:3;Parent=FBtr0280764;parent_type=mRNA

Comment: You probably need to include more code in your question, and also a test case which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Wait... did you say `FlyBase`? You do know that regexes are case sensitive, right?

Comment: It seems the problem is inconsistent labeling within the data set downloaded from flybase. I should have anticipated that.

Comment: If it's just inconsistent capitalization, adding an `i` modifier on your regexp is cheap and easy...

Comment: @gwilymh Never trust human entered data. :) Use the `/i` modifier, or selectively inside the regex, e.g. `Fly(?i:b)ase`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `x`, `m`, `i` options I would make the following changes:

`^Ch4_group[1-5] Flybase exon` 
would  be:
`^Ch4_group[1-5]\s*Flybase\sexon\s*$`

`^ChX._group[0-9]+[a-z]* Flybase exon`
 would  be:
`^ChX._group[0-9]+[a-z]*\s+Flybase\sexon\s*$`

`^Unknown_group_[0-9]+   Flybase exon`
 would be: 
`^Unknown_group_[0-9]+\s*Flybase\sexon\s*$`

`^Unknown_singleton_[0-9]+   Flybase exon` 
would be: 
`^Unknown_singleton_[0-9]+\s*Flybase\sexon\s*$`